# Migrating from ClearCase to TFS - Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: tfs, migration, out-of-memory, clearcase, tfs-migration

I'm trying to migrate a large ClearCase stream (it has a large history set too) to TFS 2010 using "TFS Integration Tools".

The tool hangs at `TfsMigrationShell.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: ClearCase history command: 'lshistory -minor -since 01-Jan-0001.00:00:00 -eventid -recurse -fmt "*%n*%o*%m*%e*%d*%Nc*%l##" -pname \IB_FE'` 
and then it gives the following run time error:
`System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.Split(String[] separator, Int32 count, StringSplitOptions options)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.ClearCaseDetailedHistoryAdapter.ClearCaseCommandSpec.ParseHistoryTable(String cmdOutput)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.ClearCaseDetailedHistoryAdapter.ClearCaseServer.GetHistoryRecords(ReadOnlyCollection'1 filters, DateTime since, Boolean writeHistoryRecordsFound)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.ClearCaseDetailedHistoryAdapter.ClearCaseAnalysisProvider.queryHistory(ChangeGroupService changeGroupService)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.ClearCaseDetailedHistoryAdapter.ClearCaseAnalysisProvider.GenerateDeltaTable()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Toolkit.AnalysisEngine.GenerateDeltaTables(Guid sourceId)`

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that:

- a `cleartool lshistory -minor` can be *huge* for a repo with a large history
- it also can be incomplete, since Vob scrubbing is run every week, unless those jobs have been modified to keep them. See "[Keep minor event records after scrubbing a VOB database](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124633)"

Since you cannot modify the tool in order to import only up to a certain data "d1", the "d1" to "d2", and so on until "present day", I would really consider:

- importing only a very short history of ClearCase into TFS (the last 5 baselines for instance, if you were using ClearCase UCM)
- keeping ClearCase in read-only mode, if you need to go back to older history (for archive).

Answer (score 0):

You have a System.OutOfMemoryException raised, looks like you need more free RAM/Paging for the tool to run.

Close all the running applications you can, make sure the System Paging file is big enough (three times the amount of RAM, for instance).

Then try again.